Amazon Aurora MySQL slow to count not-null column
I'm trying to figure out how I can speed up the time to get a count of all the rows in an InnoDB table. My deployment environment is AWS Aurora MySQL, but I see the same behavior in regular MySQL.
I have an indexed VARCHAR field 'zCreator' (not the primary key, which is a separate field called 'id') that happens to have a not-null value for all rows, and it's fairly fast to get a count of the rows:
mysql> show indexes from sync_fmlog;
+------------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
| Table      | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment | Visible | Expression |
+------------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
| sync_fmlog |          0 | PRIMARY  |            1 | ID          | A         |      321352 |     NULL |   NULL |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| sync_fmlog |          1 | creator  |            1 | z_Creator   | A         |         257 |     NULL |   NULL | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
+------------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
2 rows in set (0.11 sec)


mysql> select count(z_creator) from sync_fmlog;
+------------------+
| count(z_creator) |
+------------------+
|           350849 |
+------------------+
1 row in set (0.79 sec)

mysql> explain select count(z_Creator) from sync_fmlog;
+----+-------------+------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+--------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table      | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows   | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+--------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | sync_fmlog | NULL       | index | NULL          | creator | 258     | NULL | 254782 |   100.00 | Using index |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+--------+----------+-------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.04 sec)

However, if I want to enforce that this field is not-null, like this:
alter table sync_fmlog modify z_Creator varchar(255) not null;

Then my count becomes very slow, even though it returns the same results:
mysql> show indexes from sync_fmlog;
+------------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
| Table      | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment | Visible | Expression |
+------------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
| sync_fmlog |          0 | PRIMARY  |            1 | ID          | A         |      321352 |     NULL |   NULL |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| sync_fmlog |          1 | creator  |            1 | z_Creator   | A         |         257 |     NULL |   NULL |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
+------------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
2 rows in set (0.30 sec)

mysql> select count(z_creator) from sync_fmlog;
+------------------+
| count(z_creator) |
+------------------+
|           350849 |
+------------------+
1 row in set (13.14 sec)

mysql> explain select count(z_Creator) from sync_fmlog;
+----+-------------+------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+--------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table      | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows   | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+--------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | sync_fmlog | NULL       | index | NULL          | creator | 257     | NULL | 306471 |   100.00 | Using index |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+--------+----------+-------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.04 sec)

Why does this happen? Is there any efficient way to get an accurate count of all rows for an InnoDB table?

If you repeat the query, does it get faster? It may just need to "warm up" the storage and get the pages into RAM.

If z_Creator  can't be null, the count(*) can be used.

@BillKarwin no, the speed is consistent across multiple consecutive queries.

@Wiimm count(*) is the same speed as the slow results after I set it to not null. That’s the problem I’m trying to solve by counting a different field.

For your question, it would be good to show the creation of a table and indexes. And execution plan.
